# How does the Token Program CLI tool find token accounts

Tags: spl-token-program

Since addresses of token accounts do not necessarily need to be PDAs following a seed pattern that makes it easy to find them again by deriving the PDA using the pattern information, I wonder how tools like the Token Program CLI actually find the correct token account for an owner/mint pair. Are these tools actually fetching through all accounts of type `Account` owned by the Token Program and compare the fields `owner` and `mint` with the search parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual cli function calls the [getTokenAccountsByOwner](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountsbyowner) rpc method. The rpc indexes token accounts to allow this function to be easily called.

More generally though the [getProgramAccounts](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getprogramaccounts) can be called to return all accounts owned by a program with given filters.